# Can build without issue, but deploying to an Android device I get NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: android, libgdx

Deploying to a new Samsung tablet, my game is crashing with this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/Reader;)V in class Lorg/json/JSONTokener; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONTokener' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

However, my game compiles without issue.  I can also run it on the desktop without issue.  The class in question, JSONTokener, is in a jar file which I have included with this statement in the core project gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar') 
}
```

Again, it compiles fine.  But deploying on an Android device at runtime, judging by the exception, it finds the class, but cannot find the method; if it couldn't find the class I would see ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: The Android framework also provides `org.json.JSONTokener` - more than likely the device is loading the framework version rather than the one in the JAR you're including, and they're incompatible. What's the JAR you're including? Do you have control over it (e.g. can you view and edit the source, dependencies, build it yourself, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks!!! I thought that might be the case, but I am new to Android development so wasn't sure.  The jar I have is downloaded from https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java.  I don't have much control over it, but if Android already has an implementation I will use that instead.  Do you have more information about the Android framework's JSONTokener class?

Comment: Actually I should ask what jar and where do I find the org.json jar used by Android?

Comment: It's part of the Android framework itself - you don't need a JAR :) See the Android framework documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary).

Comment: Also, there's a great page on the github wiki for the JSON-java project about using it with Android - see [here](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/wiki/JSON-Java-for-Android-developers).

Answer (score 0):

So what clownba0t said is correct.  This is a libGDX project, and to be honest I am not very familiar with what is going on in the project setup and Gradle, etc.

The following is a bit libGDX specific, but I will try to speak generically so it may help others.

In my "android" module, I can see the build.gradle file references Android framework stuff:

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
compileSdkVersion 29
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

}
...
```

As a result, in the android module I can reference the org.json package by default.
My "core" module build.gradle file, however, does not have the Android framework, so to reference the org.json package I need to include it specifically:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20190722'
}
```

The problem comes when deploying to a device, the version of org.json in the Android framework takes precedence, and the Android framework's implementation of the org.json package is different with the latest jar file--some methods are missing.

So what did I do?  Instead of trying to figure out how to get past the name conflicts, or rewrite my code to use libGDX's JSON parsing, which I just found out about recently, I made sure my code worked within the Android framework's subset of the org.json package.